# What is the subject and object in this quote by Pablo Picasso

Tags: sentence-construction, subjects, objects

> I am always doing that which I cannot do, in order that I may learn how to do it. - Pablo Picasso

Is this a good sentence construction?

The subject is "I," but is there more than one subject in it?

Comment: Apart from ***I***, what else do you think could possibly be a "subject" here, and why?

Comment: @FumbleFingers i don't think there is another subject, right?

Comment: I can assure there's only one subject. But because I don't understand why you think there might be others, I don't understand what you're actually asking. At the levewl of *What's the grammatical subject here*, your example sentence is no different to, say, *I watch the TV news so I know what's happening in the world*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got my answer now. Thanks! one more question though. What is the subject in " .... but is there more than one subject in it?"

Comment: Your *Is there more than one subject in it?* (ignore syntactically irrelevant ***but***) is just the "question-inverted" version of the statement *There is more than one subject in it.* The precise status of the word ***there*** is a bit difficult for me to explain, but I'm sure most people would say the "subject" is simply the highlighted words that become more obvious if we rephrase that to ***More than one subject** is in it.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers hmmm, thanks..... I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly complex sentence. I guess I can see your confusion.

There are two distinct clauses, separated by the comma, Within the first clause there is a subordinate clause, beginning with "which". Each of these clauses has a subject and two of them have objects.

Breaking this up, there's:

> I am always doing that

Subject: "I". Object: "that"

> which I cannot do

This clause acts as an adjective modifying "that". What things is he talking about? Things "which I cannot do". The subject of this clause is "I". It has no object.

> in order that I may learn how to do it

"In order that" acts as a conjunction to connect this clause to the preceding clause. Ignoring this leaves "I may learn how to do it". Subject: "I". Object: "how". What am I learning? I am learning how.